# get the correct path for the file saved in sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

i am recording sound and saving in the sdcard in one activity.now that recording i had to play on the other next activity.i am getting the file path from `Uri` and `getabsolutepath()`.

but with Uri i am getting the path like

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/myfolder/filename.mp3
```

and with `getabsolutepath()` i am getting path as like.

```
/mnt/sdcard/myfolder/filename.mp3
```

this thing i am getting when running app in emulator.so is there anything so that i can get 
the file path as /myfolder/filename.mp3.

/myfolder/filename.mp3 want to save in some string so to pass to the other activity as i had mentioned above.

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
 File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File myDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "Your file name");
```

You will get your directory path here `myDir`

Answer (score 0):

always use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() if you are using external storage else give path of your internal location